# Operation not working when using number properties (returns NaN)

Tags: javascript

What's the problem in using number properties? I'm trying to do a simple calculation involving numbers and it returns NaN.

```
function test () {
    var that = this;

    this.usersCount = 2;
    this.totalSeeds = 10;

    this.test2 = function () {
        console.log(2/10*100); // 20
        console.log(that.usersCount * that.totalSeeds); // 20
        var percentUsersCount = that.usersCount / that.totalseeds * 100; // also tried parseInt() and Number()
        console.log(percentUsersCount); // NaN -- WHY !?!
    }
}

var test = new test();

test.test2();

var test1 = 2;
var test2 = 10;
var percent = test1 / test2 * 100;
console.log(percent); // 20
```

Why is `percentUsersCount` NaN?

http://jsfiddle.net/ht2rv1ea/

Edit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI6VXlNRrI0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled the name of your variable. Use `that.totalSeeds` instead of `that.totalseeds`.

Comment: You javascript console should have thrown an error for this, check it next time! :-)

Comment: I was in my console already, to view the console.logs I put in, but it didn't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
  var percentUsersCount = that.usersCount / that.totalseeds * 100;
```

Change to

```
  var percentUsersCount = that.usersCount / that.totalSeeds * 100;
```